# Как динамически загрузить DLL и функцию из неё?

Tags: delphi, dll

Данный код загружает dll, но не загружает функцию из нее (`addr(wsRoPT)` возвращает `nil`).

```
type
  TFunc2Double = function (P:double;T:double):double; 
var
  dllHandle:THandle;
  wsRoPT:TFunc2Double; 
begin
  dllHandle:= LoadLibrary('ws.dll');
  if dllHandle<>0 then
  begin
    @wsRoPT:= GetProcAddress(dllHandle,'wsRoPt');
    if addr(wsRoPT)<>nil then
      WRoEdit.Text:=FloatToStr(wsRoPT(p,t))
    else
      ShowMessage('0');
end;
```

В dll функция имеет следующий вид:

```
function wsRoPT(P:double;T:double):double;
```

Ошибка появляется в месте, до этого все нормально.

```
@wsRoPT:= GetProcAddress(dllHandle,'wsRoPt');
```

Ошибка: не найден указанный модуль.

Comment: Проверьте код, вы где-то `end` потеряли?

Comment: Которая из двух API возвращает ошибку? И что при этом возвращает GetLastError? Без этой информации гадать можно очень долго...

Comment: Процедура addr(wsRoPT) возвращает nil

Comment: Скорее всего Name Mangling и внутри DLL имя выглядит не как "wsRoPt", попробуйте объявить его в коде DLL как extern "C"

Comment: статически эта функция загружается без проблем. Использую это же имя

Comment: Где находится dll? Возможно, играет роль DLL Search Order https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx  
Попробуйте указать полный путь к dll

Comment: В той же папке, но статически же библиотека загружается

Comment: Возможно проблема в том, что функций называется wsRoP**T**, а ищете вы функцию wsRoP**t** ...

Comment: я уже давно переименовал

Comment: А что именно Вы переименовали?..

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте модифицировать функцию вот так и посмотрите какая ошибка происходит?

```
type
  TFunc2Double = function (P:double;T:double):double; 
var
  dllHandle:THandle;
  wsRoPT:TFunc2Double; 
begin
  dllHandle:= LoadLibrary('ws.dll');
  if dllHandle <> 0 then
  begin
    @wsRoPT:= GetProcAddress(dllHandle,'wsRoPt');
    if @wsRoPT <> nil then
      WRoEdit.Text:=FloatToStr(wsRoPT(p,t))
    else ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
  end else ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
end;
```

Кстати, по-умолчанию функция вызывается с соглашением вызова **register**, ws.dll написана на delphi?

---

добавлено в 14:40

Тогда возможно у вас действительно ошибка в названии процедуры, как написал [kodv](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/196135/kodv), т.к. из описания GetProcAddress: `The spelling and *case* of a function name pointed to by lpProcName must be identical to that in the EXPORTS statement of the source DLL's module-definition (.def) file.`

Comment: `Addr` в Делфи тоже есть, работает идентично `@` емнип, но возможно есть какие-то различия.

Comment: Да, уже нашёл, наследие паскаля, её даже из справки в XE вырезали.

Comment: Справка кстати говорит, что разница есть: The @ operator is similar to the Addr function, but the @ operator can return a typed pointer if you use the $T or $TypedAddress directive. Что впрочем к делу уже не относится.

Comment: Т.к. откомментировать ниже не могу: строки `@ProcVar := ` и `ProcVar = ` в Delphi (7й по кр. мере) - тождественны, т.к. в случае процедурных типов оператор @ возвращает не адрес переменной, но адрес процедуры. Из справки: `@F converts F into an untyped pointer variable that contains an address, and @MyFunction returns the address of MyFunction.` и `The @ operator can also be used to assign an untyped pointer value to a procedural variable. For example,

var StrComp: function(Str1, Str2: PChar): Integer;
 ...
@StrComp := GetProcAddress(KernelHandle, 'lstrcmpi');`

Comment: Ошибка: не найден указанный модуль. После 2-го if. (if @wsRoPT <> nil )

Comment: Тогда есть подозрение что на том компьютере, где не работает, загружается какая-то другая ws.dll, в которой нет функции 'wsRoPt'. Попробуйте сделать поиск по всем дискам этого файла.

Comment: Так же можно в LoadLibrary для проверки прописать полный путь к заведомо правильной библиотеке.

Answer (score 1):

В этой строчке:

```
@wsRoPT:= GetProcAddress(dllHandle,'wsRoPt');
```

оператор `@` лишний.

```
wsRoPT:= GetProcAddress(dllHandle,'wsRoPt');
if Assigned(wsRoPT) then
```

Comment: Это комментарий или ответ на вопрос? )

Comment: @KromStern, по моему, очевидно, что это ответ. Разве нет? Что делает конструкция `@wsRoPT:=` ? Присваивает новое значение адресу переменной. А требуется записать значение в переменную.

Comment: Так и напишите в ответе ;-)

Comment: Это не решает проблему

Comment: Покажите как эта функция экспортируется из библиотеки.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключалась в том что я весь этот код использовал внутри контрукции     with. Когда я вынес его оттуда, то все заработало.

Comment: Вот поэтому обычно говорят: приводите **весь** код, который не работает... :)

Comment: А еще лучше - составьте минимальный воспроизводимый код. В процессе убирания лишнего как раз ошибки и находятся ;-)